# Why is php extension served by apache and a php file with proprietary extension served by FPM/FastCGI?

Tags: php, apache, session, fpm

After a recent update of PHP we where confronted with sessions getting lost between two files. The two files are of different extensions but both PHP. After research we found the .php files are served Server API Apache 2.0 in PHP version 7.3.22. The proprietary extension (pext) however is served by Server API FPM/FastCGI also in PHP version 7.3.22. We assume this is the reason the session is not transferred.

We use this rule in htaccess to get our proprietary extension served as PHP:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .pext

We would like to know how to setup so both extensions are served by the same Server API so the can share session data.

Answer (score 1):

Found it: from php 7.2 another php.conf file is created: php72-php.conf which do not copy the following setting;

<FilesMatch .(php|pext)$>
SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm

Therefor - as per default - the new php.conf set Server API Apache to php and pext was left with FPM. After adding above and restarting FPM and Apache all was fine and sessions are shared again.